# Bootstrap not being applied properly in angular

Tags: css, angular, frontend, npm-install, bootstrap-table

I'm trying something very simple to understand what's going on:

1. I create a new Angular project with `ng new`
2. After setting the configuration of the project, I install the dependencies with `npm i bootstrap`
3. I know there are many ways of adding bootstrap to the project. I'm using the method of adding the following code to the styles.scss file: `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` (I've also tried to add the dependencies to the angular.json file)

I'm trying to create a table with a dark header (`thead-dark`) and the table is being created, but the theme not applied.

**Expected result**

[image]

**Actual result**

[image]

Comment: I'm using both, Chrome and Firefox. Both have the same effect

Comment: open browser console and see if any error or message there or not ?

Comment: Nope! No logs outputed. The table is displayed as it should, but the thead-dark is not working. However, if I change the code to "table-dark" (which is not really what I want), that works. There are some bootstrap directives that work fine (such as btn-danger, btn-success)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm i bootstrap` will install you the latest version of Bootstrap which is 5. Bootstrap 5 does not include `thead-dark` class and that is why your header isn't rendering dark.

Since you are using Bootstrap 5 you should be using `table-dark` class instead of `thead-dark`.

See documentation at: [Bootstrap 5 Tables (thead)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#table-head)

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark"> <!-- change this -->
    <!-- -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And if you need Bootstrap 4, check out this blog tutorial for an installation guide [Angular 10 with Bootstrap 4](https://www.kiltandcode.com/2020/07/16/how-to-add-bootstrap-4-to-an-angular-10-app/)